# py3.11: Unable to install pip packages (directly or using requirements.txt)

Tags: tcp, pip, package

I have just cloned one of my repos from github to work on it only to be met with this error:

```
$ pip install -r deps/requirements.txt
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f287e110a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/django/
```

i have also tried to install packages directly:

```
$ pip install django
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc4e628ba10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/django/
```

i have also tried clearing cache but the problem still persists.

Why is my pip fetching from `/simple/django/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to make things work by changing `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Added these lines
nameserver 8.8.4.4 # Added these lines
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

Relied on this question: [How do I add a DNS server via resolv.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

**Update:**

Unfortunately, my method gets overwritten on reboot, I will keep digging for ways to make it permanent.

**Update #2**

I have managed to make my changes permanent by updating `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`, on every `@reboot` the system will append the content of the file to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
# Add these lines to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```